# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 521

Tags: laravel-5.3

when i try to run the /logout path in the default login it gives me this error
what should i do?

```
in RouteCollection.php line 218
2.at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
3.at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
4.at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
5.at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
6.at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
7.at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
8.at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
9.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
10.at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
11.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
12.at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
13.at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
14.at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
15.at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Auth::routes method in laravel 5.3 registers a POST route for /logout instead of a GET route. This prevents other web applications from logging your users out of your application. To upgrade, you should either convert your logout requests to use the POST verb or just register your own GET route for the /logout URI by adding this route to the file Routes/web.php:-
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

and it should work fine and redirect you to the '/' directory as it's defined in the LoginController.php

Here is the documentation , 9th paragraph i think it is 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade